# Is this printf expression safe?

Tags: c, printf

I am just wondering if this expression is safe :

```
int main (void)
{
  char my_tab[256]={0x18}; /* not '\0' */

  printf("Is it safe ? : %.256s",my_tab); /* is it safe ? */
}
```

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Yes. The remaining elements of `my_tab` are implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: Don't modify your question completely like that. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Ok I will create a new one.

Comment: My question was not well written, so I have created a new one : "printf : Is this safe?" Sorry for this issue.

Comment: Perhaps better delete this question.

Comment: I can't, it is not available... I asked for closing to a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worrying whether `my_tab` is null-terminated, don't.

```
char my_tab[256]={0x61};
```

is equivalent to:

```
char my_tab[256]={0x61, 0, 0, 0 /* omits others */, 0};
```

I've omitted the other 0s, all elements not explicitely initialized are initialized to `0`.

Comment: See my modifications. (Thank you for you answer by the way)

Answer (score 1):

It shall be. According to the manpage of `printf` describing the precision:

> #### The precision
>
> ...or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions.

So access to `my_tab` shall not beyond the boundary.